Alpha Clip not working in Blender 4.2
I'm following the tutorial how on to make a plant from textures.com and during the process I stumbled on this part where I must turn on the "Alpha clip" option into the material settings.

My problem is that when I turn on the "Alpha Clip" it simply won't work and stay at "Alpha Hashed" whatever I do.



Render engines : Cycles


Alpha Clip is an Eevee settings, I have no idea how you did get access to it with Cycles. It shouldn't happen.

When I switch to Eevee, the above-mentionned panel containing the Alpha Clip and other options simply disappears : https://i.postimg.cc/fTkyCksn/alpha-clip-not-here.png

That's not Eevee settings you are showing, these are Cycles settings.

the very link I just posted is after I turned on the Eevee

Nevermind I may be wrong (see Crantisz answer), it may well be Eevee but with the new 4.2 setting.

In Cycles, the Viewport Display section shows Eevee settings. In 4.2, it incorrectly still showed the old Eevee options, see this bug report. It will be fixed in the next Blender version.

Check out last changes in EEVEE:

Material Blend Mode was replaced by Render Method. To reproduce the
same behavior as the former Alpha Clip or Opaque, materials need be
modified by adding a Greater Than Math mode.

So to reproduce the same effect in 4.2, add a Math node between texture and opacity socket, and set the mode to Greater Than
